# Is it also possible that the line intersects the curve at one point?

Tags: vector-analysis

I am looking at the Green theorem:

$$\text{ Let S be a simple closed curve of the plane xy,}\\ \text{such that a line that is parallel to each of the axes intersects the curve S at , at most, two points. } $$

Does this mean that the line should intersect the curve at no point or two points?

Or is it also possible that the line intersects the curve at one point?

Comment: Yep, it is a tangent.

Comment: No point, one point or two points. That's what "at most two points means". There will always be lines parallel to one of the axes that don't intersect the curve at all, and if there is no such line that intersects the curve in only one point, there are lines that intersect the curve in more than two points.

Comment: So,the only possible line,that intersects the curve at one point is the tangent? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

One point is also possible. The curve could be a circle, and a horizontal  line through the bottom-most point intersects it in one point, and that's fine.

Comment: So,the only possible line,that intersects the curve  at one point is the tangent? Or am I wrong?

Comment: "Tangent" implies that the curve is differentiable at the point of intersection.  Consider a square that is rotated 45 degrees, so that its center is the origin and each of its vertices lie on the axes.  Then the horizontal line that passes through the vertex on the positive y-axis certainly intersects at only a single point, but it isn't 'tangent.'

Comment: Also, think of the graph of $y = x^3$, and the $x$-axis. That line touches the curve at only one point, but unlike the circle case, it also *crosses* the curve. So the circle example is a good one, but not every feature of it is essential, as @Hayden's answer (and this one) show.